# How to change variable onclick

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");

let input = document.getElementById("input");

let num = '0';

let button = document.getElementById("button");

let button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

button2.onclick = () => {
    num = '1'
}

if (num == '1') {
    button.onclick = () => {
        text.textContent = input.value
    }
}
```

I need to activate this code if num variable is `1`

```js
button.onclick = () => {
    text.textContent = input.value
}
```

This code doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: `if (num == '1') {` runs only once, at the beginning of pageload

Comment: when your code runs the condition is `false` and then never checked again. Wrap it inside a function and call that function when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the if clause inside the click event:

```
button.onclick = () => {
    if (num === 1) {
        text.textContent = input.value
    }
}
```

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input")
let button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2")
let text = document.getElementById("text")

let num = 0

button1.onclick = () => {
    if (num === 1) {
        text.textContent = input.value
    }
}

button2.onclick = () => {
    num = 1
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button id="button2">Click me first</button>
<button id="button1">Click me second</button>
<span id="text"></span>
```